# Configure Internet option from remote for windows 8

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, lan

I want to configure internet option via remote for windows 8. For example, I some pcs have two accounts, say admin,user. All pc connected via LAN with a server. How do I disable and enable internet from centralized server for only those users who have logged in via 'user' account? I asked for windows 8 machines.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be some kind of Centralized authentication and authorization.
Like the Microsoft ActiveDirectory, or An OpenLDAP Server.
Next you would need a proxy server where every program/user has tho authenticate to open up a new Connection to the outside world.

Another approach could be some kind of captive portal on your router (pfsense does this pretty easy and fast) for authentication.
This could also be paired with a centralized user management oder just local users.

Local Users (on every machine) have the problem that none of the settings and properties, such as passwords, could be synchronized and have to be set by hand on every machine.